# Android - support.v4.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I read Android documentation on how to add a Fragment to an activty. It says that to add a Fragment to an Activty I should write this code inside the Activity class:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but this is for android.app.Fragment class.
For android.support.v4.Fragment, documentation say that instead of getFragmentManager() I should call getSupportFragmentManager() and that Activity must extends FragmentActivty.
So I did this change, and now this is my activity code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

AppCompactActivity is a subclass of FragmentActivity so I respected the constraints.

The problem is that if I run my application I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    com.myapplication.ExampleActivity@13388c6 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

I typed OnFragmentInteractionListener on Android doc web search and this is what I get:
[image]

Immediately below there is the link
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

that shows me a guide to communication between fragments. It speaks about ListFragment and I don't care it.

I'm very very confuse because every time I read documentation there are always things that force me to make internet search to find workaround or fix to problems.

Is there a persone that can explain me first how to fix this problem.

Comment: what did you not understand with `com.myapplication.ExampleActivity@13388c6 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`? it's prolly thrown from `Fragment.onAttach` because Fragment implementation expects to gets Activity which implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: So, what I have to do? Do I have to move the code from `onCreate()` to `onAttach()`?

Comment: Well, you have to learn reading with understanding

Comment: I understood that Fragment expects that `Activty` implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. Is what I wrote in the question. What I would to know is how to to this, because, as I said, I cannot find this interface in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), you can read the following:

> In order to receive event callbacks from the fragment, the activity
>   that hosts it must implement the interface defined in the fragment
>   class.

So, implement it in your Activity with something like this in your fragment:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article
    }
}
```

Why did you need it? Because you've forced the host activity to implement it with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is `HeadlinesFragment`? Is not part of Android API if I guess.

Comment: No, that's just an example. It should be your `ExampleFragment`

Comment: Check in `ExampleFragment` for`public void onAttach(Activity activity) ` method.

Comment: I still don't understand. I read the tutorial. Maybe is not what I want. Because I don't like that to add a single fragment I have to write all this code. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: That's an implementation of Listener/Callback pattern. When you have something to tell from Fragment to the host Activity, you telling the activity from the listener.